# fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/lambda-pipeline-repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

I am trying to set up My AWS code commit to my local system.

I am trying to clone the repo

```
git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/lambda-pipeline-repo
```

when I tried to do that I get this window where I enter my IAM user credentials.

[image]

Soon after this, I get

```
Cloning into 'lambda-pipeline-repo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/lambda-pipeline-repo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

I also tried things in this link

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html
```

Could anyone help me out of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the AWS docs out here for the fix on windows : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/troubleshooting-ch.html
It should be due to credential helper doesn't connect to the credentials properly for some reason.

(I had the same issue on Mac. Once the aws credential helper and osxkeychain credential helper were restored as instructed in the doc, things were working fine.)

See if that helps. - Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have tried multiple ways as mentioned in other links of Stack Overflow, GitHub portals, AWS help site not worked for me.

The method worked for me is as below.

1. In IAM, select the "Security Credentials"
2. In My Security Credentials choose the "AWS CodeCommit Credentials"
3. Under HTTPS Git credentials for AWS CodeCommit, click "Generate credentials"
4. Use the username & password that got generated.

NOTE: Before this kindly delete the previous credential used.

Steps to delete your Credential Manager

1. Control Panel
2. Select "Credential Manager"
3. Under Generic Credential, delete the appropriate Git Credential.